# Что значат эти записи , как выглядит их полный эквивалент

Tags: c

```
if(b) printf("%d\n", a/b);
while(!done)
```

Почему такая запись используется , как выглядят они без такого условия управления , можете привести примеры еще подобных условий ,
Я правильно понимаю, что это всё основывается на том, что тело цикла будет выполнятся , если значение условия не 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иначе можно записать как:

```
if (b != 0) printf ("%d", a/b);
while (done == 0)
```

код у вас неполный: после `while` должен быть либо код, либо `;`

Запись, которую вы привели в вопросе строится на том, что значения true и false - это тоже числа. При этом false всегда равно 0. True != 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(b) printf("%d\n", a/b);
```

если `b` не равно нулю, вывести значение `a/b`, причем, хочется верить, что `a` - целочисленная переменная, т.к. спецификатор формата -`%d`.

```
while(!done)
```

Не законченный цикл - отсутствует тело. Будет выполняться, пока значение переменной `done` - нулевое.

Comment: Разве что стоит добавить, что вычисление "done", скорее всего, происходит где-то в другом потоке.